# Método get de tipo String me devuelve el String incompleto. JAVA

Tags: java, get

Tengo una clase `Queja` con un atributo `descripcion` de tipo *String* que lleno a través de la clase Scanner.
Resulta que cuando quiero recuperar el dato me devuelve sólo la primera palabra del texto que metí.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*******Nueva queja***********");
        
        System.out.println("Descripcion");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Queja q=new Queja();
        String descripcion=sc.next();
        q.setDescripcion(descripcion);

        //clase para setear quien recibe la qeja.
        ControlReceptor controlR=new ControlReceptor();
          
        System.out.println("***************************");
        System.out.println(q.getDescripcion());
        System.out.println(q.getRecibidaPor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Diferencia entre next y nextLine en Java***

**next()** solo lee hasta donde encuentra un espacio (hasta un espacio).

**nextLine()** lee todo incluyendo espacios (hasta un enter).

```
 String descripcion=sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Que grande capo. Gracias. Ya funciono. Entendido las diferecias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría leer un poco de la documentación de [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html).

En tu caso se soluciona con [Scanner.nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) que lee la entrada de texto hasta: Encontrar un salto de línea o que se terminó el archivo

[Scanner.next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) por el contrario lee hasta que se encuentra con un delimitador como: espacio, salto de línea, tabulador, etc.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo. estoy iniciando en java. Voy a ller la doc.